# React only removes last item from array on re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Removing an item from array causes React to only remove the last item in that rendered array rather than the element that was actually removed. Here's the code:

```
<View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
      {this.props.items.map((tag, i) => <Tag key={i}
                                             value={tag}
                                             style={[styles.tag, this.props.tagStyle]}
                                             onRemoveTag={this.removeTag.bind(this)}/>)}
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the component's key to something uniquely identifiable to the component instead of the index seems to do the trick:

```
<View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
      {this.props.items.map(tag => <Tag key={tag}
                                             value={tag}
                                             style={[styles.tag, this.props.tagStyle]}
                                             onRemoveTag={this.removeTag.bind(this)}/>)}
    </View>
```

Comparisons for arrays re-renders must be done using the keys rather than the component itself.